# How do I check stability margins for a LQR with integral action?

Tags: matlab, control-theory, simulation, optimal-control, kalman-filter

As we know, a LQG has no guaranteed stability margins. And that's very bad if you seeking robustness for a system.

But a LQR has guaranteed stability margins and a LQR has very high strength against disturbances.

Here is a diagram of a LQR with integral action:

[image]

And here is the state space model:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\ 
\dot{x_i}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\ 
-C & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
x_i
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\ 
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u\\ 
r
\end{bmatrix} \\ u = L x + L_i x_i
$$

I know that the transfer function of the model is:
$$ G_{SYS}(s) = C(s I - A)^{-1} B$$

And the transfer function of the whole LQR-system:

$$G_{LQR}(s) = L(s I - A)^{-1} B$$

But when I have a integral action included into the LQR system. What will the transfer function be then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the transfer function of the openloop system, so your first transfer function. However your second transfer function is wrong, because the poles of that closed loop can be unstable if the eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the right half plane. I am not entirely sure where you define the input for LQR, so I am not sure about the matrices you have to pre and post multiply, however in the middle you should have $(s\,I - A - B\,L)^{-1}$. This should make sure that the closedloop poles will be located in the open left half plane.

For the transfer function of the LQR with integral action you can use the fact that the Laplace transform of the derivative of $x$ is equal to $s$ times Laplace transform of $x$. So using that $u = L\,x + L_i\,x_i$, then the differential equation can also be written as

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{x}_i
\end{bmatrix}}_{\dot{z}} = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
A+B\,L & B\,L_i \\
-C & 0
\end{bmatrix}}_{A_z}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ x_i
\end{bmatrix}}_{z} + 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ I
\end{bmatrix}}_{B_z} r.
$$

Taking the Laplace transform from both sides, while using that $X(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $x(t)$, and then solving for $Z(s)$ yields

$$
s\,Z(s) = A_z\,Z(s) + B_z\,R(s),
$$

$$
Z(s) = \left(s\,I - A_z\right)^{-1} B_z\,R(s).
$$

The output of the system is defined as $y = C\,x + D\,u$, so the transfer function from the input $r(t)$ to the output $y(t)$ can be written as

$$
G_{LQI}(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)} = \begin{bmatrix}
C+D\,L & D\,L_i
\end{bmatrix}\left(s\,I - A_z\right)^{-1} B_z.
$$

This is the closedloop, also known as the complimentary sensitivity. But in order to calculate the margins of this control law you need the openloop, plant times controller $G_{SYS}(s)\,K(s)$. The complimentary sensitivity and this openloop are related as follows

$$
G_{LQI}(s) = (I + G_{SYS}(s)\,K(s))^{-1} G_{SYS}(s)\,K(s).
$$

Solving this equation for the openloop yields

$$
G_{SYS}(s)\,K(s) = G_{LQI}(s) (I - G_{LQI}(s))^{-1}.
$$

For this openloop transfer function you can draw the Bode and/or Nyquist diagram and extract the margins you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can solve the Nyquist kriteriet to check if the model have stability margins. Do you know why LQR have stability margins(and is very robust) and LQG have no guaranteed stability margins?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I always imagined that if you have very bad signal to noise ratio then it's hard to construct a good estimate, usually especially at high frequencies. So if you have an aggressive state feedback (very large Q with respect to R) then you are trying to cancel part of the estimated state induced by the noise. One might be able to say something about the stability margins if you lower Q with respect to R far enough. Especially for LQI, since the integral guarantees high gain at low frequencies. However I have not looked into any proof for this myself, so I might be wrong.

Comment: So with integral action, I get more stability margins?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson It all depends on which weighting matrices you choose when solving for the LQI gain. I would say try changing these yourself and see what effect they have on your margins.

Comment: @euraad please take a look at the famous paper by Doyle https://authors.library.caltech.edu/93672/1/01101812.pdf showing by counter example that the guaranteed (stability) margins are not possible to be specified for the LQG control algorithm with the underlying intuitive being approached by the second comment on this answer.